# Query COUNT echo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have an error in counting and echoing the the answer. BTW i am Making an examination system where in I am counting how many students answer a , b ,c d

try to understand my program. I am not good in English

```
<?php
                                while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    $i = $i + 1;
                                    if ($i % 2 == 0)
                                        echo "<tr class=\"alt\">";
                                    else

                                        echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td style=\"text-align:center;\">". $i
                                    . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['question'],ENT_QUOTES) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r[htmlspecialchars_decode($r['correctanswer'],ENT_QUOTES)],ENT_QUOTES) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['marks'],ENT_QUOTES) . "</td>"
                                    . "</td></tr>";

                                        /*
                                        $query3 = "Select qnid, COUNT(stdnswer) AS ans1 FROM  studentquestion WHERE stdanswer = 'optiona' and qnid ='" . $i ."'";
                                        $query4 = "Select qnid, COUNT(stdnswer) FROM  studentquestion WHERE stdanswer = 'optionb' and qnid ='" . $i ."'";
                                        $query5 = "Select qnid, COUNT(stdnswer) FROM  studentquestion WHERE stdanswer = 'optionc' and qnid ='" . $i ."'";
                                        $query6 = "Select qnid, COUNT(stdnswer) FROM  studentquestion WHERE stdanswer = 'optiond' and qnid ='" . $i ."'";
                                    */

                                        $data = mysql_query("Select qnid, COUNT(stdnswer) AS total FROM  studentquestion WHERE stdanswer = 'optiona' and qnid ='" . $i ."'");
                                        $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);

                                        echo $info["total"];


                                }
                ?>
```

Here I am just counting How many student who answered optiona.

Comment: What is the question and what is the error?

Comment: Are you from India ? And this is wrong to say -> `please respect my question`

Comment: sorry sir. the error is IT doesnt output what is being count. it doesnt show the total per $qnid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$info = mysql_fetch_object($data);
echo $info->total_count;
```

Comment: print_r($i); 
$data = mysql_query("Select * FROM  studentquestion WHERE stdanswer = 'optiona' and qnid ='" . $i ."'");
$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
print_r($info);
can you please replace you code with this and show the output result?

Comment: the output is just the Qnid sir 123456789101112131415 :((

Comment: $data = mysql_query("Select * FROM studentquestion WHERE stdanswer = 'optiona' and qnid ='" . $i ."'"); $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data); print_r(count($info)); replace with this code and show the output result?

Comment: please mark the answer as correct so that, others can also understand the right answer :)